# Flutter position exception with geolocator

Tags: android, ios, flutter, geolocation

I'm new in flutter and I want to build a basic app in which I have to retrieve the position and based on the position I have to show different Item.

I tried to retrieve position by using of Geolocator, and it works, my problem is when I have to manage the exception.

For example when user reject permission I have to show an error, also when I have the permission but the service is disabled I have to show an other error.

If user have the service disabled and after he active it I have to reload the page and the error have to disappear.

How I can handle these cases?

that's my simple code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart' as loc;

class LocationPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LocationPageState createState() => _LocationPageState();
}

class _LocationPageState extends State<LocationPage> {
  Position _currentPosition;
  bool serviceEnabled = false;
  @override
  void initState() {

    getLocationPermission();
      _getCurrentLocation();
    super.initState();
  }

  getLocationPermission() async {

    if (!await locationR.serviceEnabled()) {
      setState(() async {
        serviceEnabled = await locationR.requestService();
        if(serviceEnabled){
          _getCurrentLocation();
        }
      });

    } else {
      setState(() {
        serviceEnabled = true;
      });
    }

  }

  String _currentAddress;
  loc.Location locationR = loc.Location();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Location"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            _currentAddress != null ? Text(_currentAddress) : serviceEnabled ? Loading() : Text("Errors"),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _getCurrentLocation() {
    Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
            desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best,
            forceAndroidLocationManager: true)
        .then((Position position) {
      setState(() {
        _currentPosition = position;
        _getAddressFromLatLng(_currentPosition);
      });
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }

  _getLastPosition() {
    Geolocator.getLastKnownPosition().then((Position position) {
      setState(() {
        _currentPosition = position;
        _getAddressFromLatLng(_currentPosition);
      });
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }

  _getAddressFromLatLng(Position position) async {
    try {
      List<Placemark> placemarks =
          await placemarkFromCoordinates(position.latitude, position.longitude);

      Placemark place = placemarks[0];

      setState(() {
        _currentAddress =
            "${place.locality}, ${place.postalCode}, ${place.country},${place.toString()}";
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

thank's all

Comment: Hi, my situation is a little more complex than yours because I need the background location. And I don't have time to give you a fuller answer. In my case I used this plugin, see if it helps. https://pub.dev/packages/location_permissions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check for the possible results from the `checkPermission` and `requestPermission` methods, which are `denied`, `deniedForever`, `whileInUse` and `forever`.

Here's an example on how to acquire the current position of the device, including checking if the location services are enabled and checking / requesting permission to access the position of the device:

```
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

/// Determine the current position of the device.
///
/// When the location services are not enabled or permissions
/// are denied the `Future` will return an error.
Future<Position> _determinePosition() async {
  bool serviceEnabled;
  LocationPermission permission;

  // Test if location services are enabled.
  serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
  if (!serviceEnabled) {
    // Location services are not enabled don't continue
    // accessing the position and request users of the 
    // App to enable the location services.
    return Future.error('Location services are disabled.');
  }

  permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
  if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
    permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      // Permissions are denied, next time you could try
      // requesting permissions again (this is also where
      // Android's shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale 
      // returned true. According to Android guidelines
      // your App should show an explanatory UI now.
      return Future.error('Location permissions are denied');
    }
  }
  
  if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
    // Permissions are denied forever, handle appropriately. 
    return Future.error(
      'Location permissions are permanently denied, we cannot request permissions.');
  } 

  // When we reach here, permissions are granted and we can
  // continue accessing the position of the device.
  return await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
}
```